# A possible Russian demonym for a citizen of Saint Kitts and Nevis?

Tags: выбор-слова

Is there a demonym in Russian for a citizen of Saint Kitts and Nevis?

Comment: do you know how is such a citizen called on English? Is there a demonym in English?

Comment: @cha - I don't think so.

Comment: Санкт-Кит-Невисовец, Санкт-Кит-Невисовка. Why asked then?

Comment: Wikipedia calls them Kittitian or Nevisian.

Comment: @cha: "Why asked then?" - Hmm... Why not? Does the absence of some terms in English automatically guarantee the absence of such in Russian?!

Comment: No it does not. But I never thought of Russian to be obsessed to put everything in one word like Germans do: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_word

Comment: @cha Почему _-овец_? Навскидку не могу вспомнить ни одной местности, название которой кончалось бы закрытым слогом и порождало бы этнохороним с помощью суффиксов _-овец_ / _-евец_ / _-инец_. Только кончающихся гласной: _Дергачи́_ → _дергачёвец_, _Мыти́щи_ → _мыти́щинец_.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov: *Орёл → орловец, Артём → артёмовец* etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Из всего многообразия русских суффиксов для образования этнохоронимов (*-як*, *-ат*, *-ич*, *-лянин*, *-чанин* и т. д.) с английскими топонимами используется *-ец*: *бирмингемец*, *бостонец*, *оттавец* и т. д.
2. Жители местностей с названиями вида *сущ. и cущ.*: *Босния и Герцеговина*, *Тринидад и Тобаго*,  вполне могут именоваться только по первому слову: *боснийцы*, *тринидадцы*.
3. Дефис при образовании этнохоронима не сохраняется: *ньюйоркец*, *санпаулец*.

Отсюда возможным названием жителя Сент-Китс и Невиса является *сентки́тсец*. Если это слово кажется труднопроизносимым, то прежде чем сдаться можно вспомнить, что Кит — это диминутив от Кристофор и Saint Christopher and Nevis — все еще [официальное название](http://www.gov.kn/) этого государства, и поздравить Павла Дурова с тем, что он стал *сенткристофо́рцем*.

Answer (score 0):

For complex country name like this, it is usually "житель Сент-Китс и Невиса"

Comment: Why not "... Сент-КитсA и Невиса"?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use the right suffix, it will not sound natural in Russian. It is hard to pronounce, the country is not very widely-known in Russia, and a Russian speaker will just get stuck thinking of the right name of the place where the person you're talking about lives. Thus, I suggest using the words "житель", "резидент": житель Сент-Китс и Невис.

The rule says that toponyms which end up with a consonant are not declined in the Russian language as well as compound toponyms: Сент-Китс.
Сент-КитсА и НевисА would sound okay if it was widely-used in Russian as, for example, Washington: житель ВашингтонА (everyone has heard about Washington).

Comment: Could you please source the rule you mention, the one which forbids declining compound toponyms?

Comment: http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_90

Comment: http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_90 Well, it actually says that foreign toponyms which end up with a consonant are not declined when they are used in the function of application (don't know the right word in English to describe a toponym which is used as the second noun: the city of Washington, not just Washington). Though, Washington is not a good example here as the rule also says that the foreign toponyms which have been used in the Russian language for quite a time ARE declined (the word 'Washington' have been used for a long-long time:)).

Comment: The word you're looking for is "apposition" (*приложение*). In *житель Сент-Китса и Невиса*, the state name is not an apposition but rather a modifier (*определение*), and, hence, the rule won't apply to this phrase.